# Galois Group, Field Extension Prove Abelian

Tags: galois-theory

Let F be an extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and let $\omega = \cos{(\frac{2\pi}{n})}\sin{(\frac{2\pi}{n})}$. Prove that $Gal(F(\omega):F)$ is abelian.

I am looking for a sketch of this proof.

so far in relation to de moirves thm i have a generic polynomial $x^n-1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$

Also $\mathbb{Q} \subseteq \mathbb{Q(\omega)}$ is a radical extension.

The order/degree/automorphisms needs to not affect communativity in order to be abelian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\zeta = \exp(\frac{2\pi i}{n})$. We have
$$\omega = \frac{1}{2}(\zeta+\zeta^{-1})\frac{1}{2i}(\zeta-\zeta^{-1}) \in \mathbb Q(i,\zeta)$$

Since the galois group of $\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q$ is well known to be an abelian group, the result follows, since $Gal(\mathbb Q(\omega)/\mathbb Q)$ is a quotient of this group.

Note that the galois group of $F(\omega)/F$ is a subgroup of $Gal(\mathbb Q(\omega)/\mathbb Q)$ by the translation theorem.

Edit: Note that $\mathbb Q(i,\zeta)/\mathbb Q$ is also an abelian extension, since its galoisgroup is either $Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q)$ or $Gal(\mathbb Q(\zeta)/\mathbb Q) \times C_2$

Comment: This must be the proof but, there is no reason to have $i\in \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$ (but you can take $\zeta'$ to be a $4n$-th root of unity, you will have $i$ and $\zeta$ in $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta')$). To apply Galois'theorem one should prove that $\mathbb{Q}(\omega)/\mathbb{Q}$ is a normal extension, I am not very sure this is clear...

Comment: Every intermediate field of an abelian extension is normal...I have reapaired the $i$-thingie..

Comment: now this is clear, thank you!